# Erro no like do SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando fazer um select onde eu quero o todos os dados de uma pessoa que tenha o mesmo ip e a data igual a data de hoje. O motivo é que preciso restringir o tanto de vezes que uma pessoa envia contato para meu sistema.

abaixo meu código.

```
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $data = date('Y-m-d');
$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_CONTATOS where TXT_ENDIP_CONTT = '.$ip.'  and DAT_INCLU_CONTT like '%".$data."%' ");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($row);

         echo $count; die;
```

Comment: Leia [isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php/3869#3869) e [isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql/4675#4675).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa do `LIKE`. Você quer algo tipo

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost dbname=teste', 'usuario', 'senha');
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_CONTATOS where TXT_ENDIP_CONTT = ? and DAT_INCLU_CONTT = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$stmt->bindValue(2, date('Y-m-d'));
$result = $stmt->execute();
$count = $result->rowCount();

echo $count; die;
```

Answer (score 2):

O erro não encontra-se no like e sim na concatenação da variável $ip

> Como a variavel já esta dentro de uma string com aspas duplas vc estava tentando concatenar com aspas simples.

**Segue abaixo exemplo de como deve ficar:**

```
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $data = date('Y-m-d');
    $row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_CONTATOS where TXT_ENDIP_CONTT = '$ip'  and DAT_INCLU_CONTT like '%".$data."%' ");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($row);

     echo $count; die;
```

Comment: Vlw deu certinho!

Comment: Por favor, considere marcar a resposta como correta isso nos incentiva a continuar ajudando a comunidade.

Comment: Ok concerteza !

Comment: Você não precisa do `LIKE`; ele impede o MySQL de usar índices pra agilizar a sua consulta.

Comment: Renan o @ctgPi está totalmente correto, considere as dicas dele também sobre SQLInjection e sobre os likes. Pois apesar de funcionar tem maneiras melhores e mais corretas de se chegar a um resultado

Answer (score 2):

A concatenação de sua string está errada. Talvez este seja seu erro.

Substitua:

```
$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_CONTATOS where TXT_ENDIP_CONTT = '.$ip.'  and DAT_INCLU_CONTT like '%".$data."%' ");
```

Por:

```
$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_CONTATOS where TXT_ENDIP_CONTT = '{$ip}' and DAT_INCLU_CONTT like '%{$data}%'");
```

Aproveito a oportunidade e recomendo a leitura e aprendizagem sobre [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score -2):

Mas seu campo data no banco de dados é tipo STRING ou DATE?

Já trabalhei com bancos que não aceitavam comparar DATE utilizando LIKE.

Comment: Isso não é uma resposta, por favor use os comentários para tirar dúvidas. Você não deve responder uma pergunta com outra pergunta.

Comment: @HiagoSouza ok. Porém não foi exatamente uma dúvida o que postei. O questionamento que coloquei foi mais para **frisar** um ponto que considerei relevante. Tanto que logo na sequência já expliquei o motivo da pergunta.

Comment: ok, mesmo assim você tinha um questionamento. Como vc mesmo disse vc explicou o motivo da "pergunta" logo não era uma resposta :) .. Então use os comentários para fazer questionamentos. :)